# Unity Weapon Switch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have weapon switch code, but when switching and it reaches an empty slot, switching stop working.
Switching button are TAB. If I change the weapon from slot 2 to slot 3 and from slot 3 to slot 1, it works well, but when switching from slot 1 (which is empty), to next slots (where are weapons), it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```cs
// Change the active weapon.
public void ChangeWeapon(int oldWeapon, int newWeapon)
{
    // Previously armed? Disable weapon.
    if (oldWeapon > 0)
    {
        weapons[oldWeapon].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        gunMuzzle = null;
        weapons[oldWeapon].Toggle(false);
    }
    // Cycle trought empty slots to find next existing weapon or the no weapon slot.
    while (weapons[newWeapon] == null && newWeapon > 0)
    {
        newWeapon = (newWeapon + 1) % weapons.Count;
    }
    // Next weapon exists? Activate it.
    if (newWeapon > 0)
    {
        weapons[newWeapon].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        gunMuzzle = weapons[newWeapon].transform.Find("muzzle");
        weapons[newWeapon].Toggle(true);
    }

    activeWeapon = newWeapon;

    // Call change weapon animation if new weapon type is different.
    if (oldWeapon != newWeapon)
    {
        behaviourManager.GetAnim.SetTrigger(changeWeaponTrigger);
        behaviourManager.GetAnim.SetInteger(weaponTypeInt, weapons[newWeapon] (int)weapons[newWeapon].type : 0);
    }

    // Set crosshair if armed.
    SetWeaponCrosshair(newWeapon > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the control if the you have a weapon and the next one is not existing, so the code is breaking. You should do something like this:

```
if(newWeapon == 0)
  {
    //set so it is going to a new condition but without having a gun showing
  }
```

Comment: Thank You, I will try and let You know If I managed to fix.